# jQuery UI CSS not coming for Dynamic HTML after On change Event

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have used jQuery UI and want to add Select HTML tag after user selects an option from the above dropdown.

When the user clicks I generate HTML, find the target and use .html() to display it.

The problem is that the jQuery UI CSS does not show for this, I get a select tag without any CSS. Used Firebug for debugging but the jQuery code is working fine. What could be the reason?

The code is

```
var srcWiseSubSrc = {
        Int    : { subsource : 'prd,ofr'},
        PNS    : { subsource:'Supplier,Buyer'},      
        PTT    : { subsource : 'ofr,prd'},  
        verify : { subsource : 'nflm,qlm,cum,nurs,nurm,mflm'}
};


        $(document).on('change' , '#source' , function() {
            var srcVal = $(this).val();
            var srcString = String(srcVal);
            var srcArr = srcString.split(",");
            var subsrcOptions = '<select id="subsrc" name="subsource[]" multiple="multiple">';
            var srcLen = srcArr.length;
            for(i=0; i< srcLen; i++)
            {
               var splitArr = srcWiseSubSrc[srcArr[i]].subsource.split(",");
               for( j=0 ; j < splitArr.length ; j++)
               {
                   subsrcOptions +='<option value="'+splitArr[j]+'">'+splitArr[j]+'</option>';    
               } 
           }
           subsrcOptions +='</select>';
           var x = $('#dynmc_subscr');
           console.log(x);
           x.html(subsrcOptions);
           console.log(subsrcOptions);
        });
```

Comment: You have not mentioned what is 'srcWiseSubSrc'. Please provide a recent code.

Comment: please post html code alse

Comment: No jquery themes match raw tags, they use classes; the `<select>` tag you generate doesn't have any. What result exactly are you going for?

Comment: Think of an example, you select an State and automaticaly u get the countries of selected state in the second select box. Same i am doing, but i have used jquery Plugin for select dropdown due to which the CSS/JS not working for Dynamic HTML Appended to second select dropdown. What could be the reason ?? Hope u got the issue.